# Title of a book telling about people teleported to a hostile planet while in deep meditation

Tags: story-identification

I read it sometime in the 90's but it seemed at least 15 years old at that time. The title might be containing something with 'wolves' or 'wilderness'.

**Alert - Spoilers below**

> The book tells of some (I think) earth cult that dictates the practice of meditation. This cult is somewhat of a scam as When reaching the top level of meditation the meditator is either teleported or his consciousness abducted (I can't remember..) to be used as a calculation machine by the abductors.

Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the title and/or author of a story about aliens hijacking the Earth and the Moon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174224/what-is-the-title-and-or-author-of-a-story-about-aliens-hijacking-the-earth-and)

Comment: Not a dup. The target does not have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

["Wolfbane"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfbane_%28novel%29) by Fred Pohl and C. M. Kornbluth fits the description.

Comment: Indeed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If it's Wolfbane, they meditated specifically on something called "Connectivity" - apparently a philosophy to reconcile them to their miserable standard of living.This was very low indeed. "Flatbelly" (ie having a stomach not bloated from hunger) was considered an insult, and perhaps brought you under suspicion of being a "wolf" who had found ways to get more than your fair share."Strider" is another schoolyard insult, as doing anything that requires a lot of energy is similarly frowned upon.

Earth has been "kidnapped" out of the Solar System, by a mobile planet inhabited by pyramid-shaped alien robots who apparently killed their creators. The Moon is at the point of balance between Earth and the Pyramids' world, and has been "ignited" to turn it into a substitute Sun.

> The hero is a "Wolf" named Glenn Tropile, who is kidnapped with three others  and taken to the Pyramids' world, where their brains are wired together to make (iirc) a sort of "computer". Tropile finds some way of freeing himself and the others and taking them back to Earth. Incidentally, one of the others is an African, and some of the comments about Africa are so "un-PC" as to make your toes curl.